# Reading text file in C++

Tags: c++, text, file-handling

I want to read a text file of the form.

```
15 23 63 52 58
11 254 55 36 22 547 55 2 
22 58 66 3 11 4 7 5 2 8 
48 49 23 88 62 33
```

How can I implement it in C++? 
The following code has been implemented by me.

```
while(!fin.eof()) {
    getline(fin, str);
    cout << str << "\n\n";
    i++;    
}
```

Here the numbers are in the form of a string.
Since the code is a part of reading adjacency list of graph, I want the array of these numbers. For example, I want to create a C++ vector array

```
vector<int> abc[4];
```

where I will store all the corresponding numbers in the line.
Please suggest a solution other than reading the numbers in form of string and splitting it. It should be concise than earlier one.

Comment: _Better_ is a relative term. What do you mean exactly? How would a solution be better than reading each line and splitting?

Comment: You don't tell us *how* you want to represent this data in your program. Is it just a `vector<double>`, or is it a `vector<vector<double>>`?

Comment: Do you want all numbers in a single collection without any regards for the line separators? Or do you want the number on each line in a separate collection?

Comment: [Don't use `!fin.eof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @KaranMehta Did you read the link?

Comment: @NathanOliver now I realize why the count in the loop was greater by 1 than the actual one..